# XAMPP: JQuery Ajax - Access-Control-Origin error

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to use JQuery ajax in order to retrieve data from a source on a different domain.

I am getting a ***No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.***

E.g. I would like to retrieve the whole DOM of e.g. stack overflow main page.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $("h1").text("Success => check console");
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $("h1").text("Error => check console");
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

**What I tried:**

- I was running this on my Apache server (XAMPP). Found out I need to set .htaccess needs to **Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"** (for security reasons the Kleene star should be replaced with the required URI). I was playing a lot with different .htaccess
- So now I am trying to retrieve it without a server on the backend, purely with the code I provided in the snippet (running it from file:///C:/)

**EDIT**

Solved the problem (also accepted my answer unless someone more skillful comes up with a better explanation) and understand the situation from a practical point of view.

*Footnote: This example is just to illustrate the problem. In the final solution, I just want to use the AJAX to send REST requests to another PC in our VLAN where a server is running.*

Comment: If it's not required by anyone else other than the computer sending the REST requests, just install the CORS chrome extension to save messing around. https://gyazo.com/166864bc90ca7517f1b82bc150d03c20

Comment: Its required by my teammates, still that is only 10-15 people.. Will present this option to the manager :) Thanks

Comment: Not the optimum solution, but is by far the fastest short term. I use it on my VPS for constant updates of CSGO weapon prices for my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts.

This is called CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). There are restrictions while making ajax request to the server other than the document's domain.

One can make a cross origin request if the request is suitable for either:

1. the request is [a simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests)
2. The other domain permits the client to access its recources.

**Why your GET request is not a simple request?**

In your case, if you *would like to retrieve the whole DOM*, the content type of the response of the GET request will be 'text/html'. And the request will not be a "simple request" any more.

So the other domain (that you want to access) has to permit for your requests:

- Permission for the document [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin). (`null` for your case)
- Permission for the [request method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Methods).

Your error message is clear enough that "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" header is not supplied by other server.

**How do you solve your problem?**

By adding your API servers "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" header. Have a look on this site: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Resources:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: The answer I provided for the question is written from a programmers point of view (and the programmer is being a beginner in this problem - I lack the proper vocabulary). Your answer is clear and professionally written and I gladly award it with the set bounty

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:

- If I host an API I need to allow cross-origin requests.
- If I want to access an API, the server hosting the API needs to allow
  cross-origin requests.
- *The code was not a problem, nor was me running it from file://, the snippet works fine*

**Longer explanation in laymans terms:**

- When hosting a server were you want to host an API, you need to allow
  **Access Control Allow Origin** headers on the server. You can specify which servers are allowed to access the API.

  If I am running an APACHE server and I want to serve some data on
  REST requests, I need to specify clients that are allowed to access
  the services I provide. This is done in .htaccess by adding:

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

  To be more secure, its possible to just allow specific origins:

  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://www.specific_origin.com
- On the other hand, if another server hosts API on their domain, the
  admin of the server needs to allow the origins they accept requests
  from (this was my case). For example, the server containing the API
  was written in python, so the code is the following:

  self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
- Once this was set, even a request from a script in the provided
  snippet works well just from accessing a *"file"* address e.g.
  `file:///C:/tasks/crawler/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you need.
I was looking into the Access-Control-Allow-Origin policy and i found this great post: [Access Control Allow Origin.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Who would downvote this? It is a very good article, indeed. While it does not explain the interface with jQuery itself, it does go through the basics of CORS step-by-step.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but this post should have been a comment, not an answer..

Comment: I agree. Advice has been taken.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to list all the addresses of all clients that will access the server.  You also need to allow OPTIONS as this is the first request type.

Try these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://clientaddress"

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "*, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin"

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS"
```

If you are passing in credentials then use:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
```

(note that cannot use Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" here if Allow-Credentials is "true")